# How do I set up local_settings.py when I have postgres specific fields?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, django-models

I am currently working with a Django application that uses a postgres database. In my local_settings.py, I use a sqlite database for local development per the code below:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
      'NAME': path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'djlocal.db'),
      'USER': '',             # Not used with sqlite3.
      'PASSWORD': '',         # Not used with sqlite3.
      'HOST': '',             # Not used with sqlite3.
      'PORT': '',             # Not used with sqlite3.
  }
}
```

When I run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot quote parameter value <django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb.JsonAdapter object at 0x000001A3B7C5B448> of type <class 'django.contrib.
postgres.fields.jsonb.JsonAdapter'>
```

Is there any way to allow the application to still work even though there are postgres specific fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to this is no. If you are using model fields that require a postgres engine (`django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb`) then these won't render the SQL flavor of another backend engine (such as sqlite).

So you won't be able to make this work without some modifications to your models.

Since your error is specifically on json field you could use a package that implements json field in a way that is not tied to an engine, but detects which engine you are using and renders the right SQL flavor.

You could use: django-jsonfield (https://pypi.org/project/django-jsonfield/). This library renders the postgres style json field if the engine is PostgreSQL and otherwise it renders it as a regular TextField with supporting serialization and deserialization and as such it does not depend on the engine and works with sqlite as well.

The usefulness of this depends on what you are doing in your code with the postgres specific json field. If you are using it only as a kind of a document store on a model, then the above is just fine. If you are using some basic lookup operators on the json field keys, you are also probably fine.

If you are doing more advanced stuff using postgres specific operators on that json field and using that in aggregates etc. then the above package probably won't be sufficient.

Let me know if this helps, or if you need clarification on any of the above.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the engine name as

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql'
```

Comment: I get this error when I do that:                                                                                          could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?